# Can I read the same topic to my toddler with two different languages from two different books at the same time?

Tags: toddler, language-development, bilingual, reading

I am not a native English speaker neither is the country I am living in. However, I want to introduce my toddler to English. Does reading the same topic for example “feelings” from different books one in my native language and another in English will confuse him?

The books are completely different. They just share the same idea/topic.

I want him to understand vocabs about this topic in both languages.

Comment: See https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/39901/36241 and give it a vote if it helps you.

Comment: I checked it. It doesn’t quite answer my concern. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: So my book example about the hares doesn't work for you... Perhaps it is my English...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a number of questions on the topic of raising bilingual children, so it's worthwhile reading them, as you'll get a much better feel for associated benefits, challenges and issues.

The simple answer from all questions on this topic is that reading books from a second language will generally not confuse children - they may well switch between languages more than you may expect, especially at a young age but they can rapidly learn to use the languages and vocabulary appropriately.

If you also have friends who are native English speakers that talk to your child in English, that will accelerate learning immensely, but they can learn even without that.